# По стойке "смирно"

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

В выражении "стоять по стойке "смирно" нужно ли "смирно" заключать в кавычки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо кавычек. Всё вместе (по стойке смирно) - нечленимый наречный оборот.  Более ранние синонимы (во фрунт, во фронт) тоже не требуют кавычек.

Единственный словарь из тех, что представлены в сети, дающий смирно в кавычках - Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007. Видимо, не авторитетен в данноьм вопросе.

Comment: Я тоже не поставила бы кавычек.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо!!! Спасили.  не могла нигде найти